# Cuál estructura gramatical hay que usar con el significado "I had been doing"

Tags: gramática, tiempos-verbales

En la página web sobre la estructura "had been doing" https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/gramatica/gramatica-britanica/past-perfect-continuous-i-had-been-working:

"We use the past perfect continuous to talk about actions or events which started before a particular time in the past and were still in progress up to that time in the past:

*It was so difficult to get up last Monday for school. I **had been working** on my essays the night before and I was very tired.* (The past perfect continuous focuses on the activity of working on the essays up to a particular time in the past.)

We can use the past perfect continuous to talk about events which started before a time in the past and which finished, but where the effects or results were still important at a point in the past:

*It **had been raining** and the ground was still wet.*"

Ya sé como decir "*have been doing*" en español, al haberlo aclarado en esta cadena [Present perfect progressive I have been doing](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/31225/23475) Pero, ¿cuál estructura gramatical hay que usar para "*had been doing*"?

En Linguee encontré algunos ejemplos:

"*In both cases, the coming together of different organisations that **had been working** in the field was the starting point for the expansion of their activities. = En ambos casos, la asociación de distintas organizaciones que ya **venían trabajando** en la materia fue el punto de partida para una expansión de su actividad.*"

"*We **had been working** on this issue for almost a year. = **Habíamos estado trabajando** en este asunto durante casi un año.*"

Personalmente yo usuaría "venía + gerundio" o "vino + gerundio". Pero tampoco sé las diferencias entre "venía + gerundio" y "vino + gerundio" porque encontré en BBC Mundo sobre la Gran Depresión (en 2:48 de https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HJFAoUU2alE):

"*Antes de la depresión del 1929, la economía ya **veniá tambaleándose***"

...Y en la película de Hollywood "Wind River" (traducida de inglés a español) en una situación en la que encontraron una mujer muerta:

"*Así que de donde sea que vino...**vino corriendo** hasta aquí...*"

Leí esta cadena - https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/eduardo-vino-ven%C3%ADa-corriendo-preterite-imperfect-gerundio.2713100/, pero todavía no entiendo al cien por cien.

Para resumir, 2 preguntas:

1. ¿Cuál estructura gramatical hay que usar para "had been doing"?
2. ¿Cuáles son las diferencias entre "venía + gerundio" y "vino + gerundio"?
3. ¿Cuáles son las diferencias entre las estructuras "había estado haciendo" vs "venía/vino + gerundio"? En realidad, no me acuerdo de encontrar la estructura "había estado haciendo" en la vida cotidiana y así que tengo una impresión de que si usara solo la estructura "venía/vino + gerundio" lo sería suficiente.

P.S. Por adelantado les agradezco a todos ustedes los que corrijan errores  si hay algunos, o en gramática o en uso de palabras o en algo más.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**¿Cuál estructura gramatical hay que usar para "had been doing"?**

El pretérito pluscuamperfecto, "había estado haciendo", es lo habitual.

**¿Cuáles son las diferencias entre "venía + gerundio" y "vino + gerundio"?**

*Venir + gerundio* es una perífrasis que describe una acción que comenzó en un momento pasado y continúa en el momento del que se habla. Así, por ejemplo, *"os vengo diciendo que hay que arreglar el tejado"* quiere decir que he estado diciendo que hay que arreglar el tejado y que continúo diciéndolo en el presente. *"Antes de la depresión del 1929, la economía ya venía tambaleándose"* quiere decir que la economía se empezó a tambalear antes de 1929 y que en 1929, cuando llegó la depresión, todavía se tambaleaba.

Sin embargo, *"vino corriendo hasta aquí"* **no** es un ejemplo de esta perífrasis. No es habitual usar la perífrasis *Venir + gerundio* en pretérito perfecto simple. En este caso, "vino" expresa la acción de desplazarse al lugar donde se encuentra el hablante, y "corriendo" es un complemento circunstancial.

**¿Cuáles son las diferencias entre las estructuras "había estado haciendo" vs "venía/vino + gerundio"?**

*Venir + gerundio* indica que la acción comenzó en un momento anterior y continúa en el momento del que se habla. *Haber estado + gerundio* (que realmente es la forma compuesta de la perífrasis *estar + gerundio*) indica que la acción comenzó en un momento anterior, pero no que continúe en el momento del que se habla (puede continuar o no).

Answer (score 1):

Sumo aquí una respuesta parcial, a pedido.

El uso del tiempo verbal “habíamos estado trabajando” es totalmente correcto. La opción de usar “veníamos trabajando” también es correcta. Las dos diferencias que pueden encontrarse entre estas dos formas son:

1. La connotación de acción sostenida, de esfuerzo continuado, que da “veníamos trabajando”. Esta perífrasis verbal es más expresiva que el tiempo verbal compuesto estándar. Si se quiere enfatizar la dificultad de mantenerse trabajando durante años, es aconsejable usar “veníamos trabajando”.
2. El registro apenas menos formal que tiene “veníamos trabajando”. Esto es en parte consecuencia del punto 1. Como es una forma más expresiva, también suena más informal que usar el tiempo verbal estándar “habíamos estado trabajando”. Esto no significa que sea inadecuada para usarla en escritos serios.

En lo personal creo que también suena y fluye mejor “ya veníamos trabajando” que “ya habíamos estado trabajando”, porque el “ya” sugiere también movimiento y continuidad. Esto es una decisión de estilo.