# Las diferencias entre estructuras "llevar + gerundio" vs "he estado + gerundio" vs "venir + gerundio" para decir "have been doing"

Tags: gramática, tiempos-verbales

En esta cadena [Present perfect progressive I have been doing](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/31225/23475) yo recibí las respuestas suficientes a la pregunta "cuál estructura puede usar para decir *have been doing*".

No obstante, querría profundizar un poco y preguntarles:

1. ¿Cuáles son las diferencias entre estructuras "*llevar + gerundio*" vs "*he estado + gerundio*" vs "*venir + gerundio*" para decir "*have been doing*"?
2. ¿Supongo que hay diferencias regionales (entre dialectos)?
3. ¿O las diferencias entre estructuras no son tan grandes comi si lo fuera necesario profundizar? ¿Que se puede usar cada uno de estas estructuras y los nativos te endenderían de todos modos?

P.S. Por adelantado les agradezco a todos ustedes los que corrijan errores  si hay algunos, o en gramática o en uso de palabras o en algo más.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Todas esas estructuras son esencialmente equivalentes y, aunque hay diferencias dialectales, todas son reconocidas por los hablantes.

Las diferencias de significado entre las estructuras son sutiles. Para un estudiante avanzado sería útil conocerlas, para poder expresar mejor ciertos matices.

*“He estado caminando”* es una estructura estándar* que sugiere que la acción sigue transcurriendo en el presente, o que tiene efectos en el presente. *“He estado caminando”* puede ir sin indicación de tiempo, o puede llevar una frase adverbial que indique un período: *“He estado caminando toda la mañana.”* No suena tan bien (por lo menos a mí) usarla con un plazo de tiempo delimitado con “desde” o “hace”. La acción puede ser continuada en el presente: *“He estado caminando toda la mañana **y todavía me queda un largo camino por delante**”*; o bien puede haber terminado ya pero tener efectos actuales: *“He estado caminando toda la mañana; **tengo que sentarme porque me duelen los pies**”*.

*“Vengo caminando”* y *“llevo caminando”* siempre sugieren que la acción continúa en el presente, y por lo general van acompañadas de una frase adverbial de tiempo. Aquí sí es natural usar “desde” o “hace”: *“Llevo/Vengo caminando desde anoche / hace tres horas / toda la mañana.”*

Hay algunas diferencias menores entre “llevo” y “vengo”, pero no sé cómo explicarlas. Yo uso ambas, a veces con los mismos verbos y en situaciones parecidas. Quizá alguien más pueda ofrecer ejemplos.

---

* En ciertas regiones el pretérito perfecto compuesto es reemplazado casi siempre por el pretérito simple, de manera que la gente dice *“estuve caminando”* aun cuando la acción siga teniendo efectos en el presente. (*“Estuve caminando”* también puede indicar una acción terminada en un punto del pasado.)

Comment: Entendido. Para aclarar todo, también buscaba una respuesta sobre "llevar + gerundio" vs "venir + gerundio" y encontré este fuente. Puede decir si es confiable? Por cierto, usé este web sitio para aclarar con éxito las diferencias sobre "no obstante" vs "sin embargo", así que interesante saber también su opinion sobre este recurso. https://www.espanolavanzado.com/gramatica-avanzada/526-venir-gerundio#:~:text=venir%2Fllevar%20%2B%20gerundio,-To%20talk%20about&text=As%20discussed%20previously%2C%20ir%2Bgerundio,that%20have%20an%20implicit%20endpoint.

Comment: en esta página se puede encontrar la información acerca de este recurso. https://www.espanolavanzado.com/sobre-nosotros ¿Usted qué opina?

Comment: Puedo añadir que tengo algunas dudas de este recurso, como era en caso de realfastspanish. Pero no tan grandes. Y puedo ser equivocado. Y por eso me interesa su opinion, si no le importa.

Comment: Al menos en lo que se refiere a este tema, me parece que es un recurso muy bueno. Las diferencias que menciona son todas correctas (solo que a mí no se me habían ocurrido).

Comment: Por cierto, puedes tutearme (usar el *tú* en vez de *usted* y sus formas verbales correspondientes). Es lo que hacemos todos aquí entre nosotros. (Personalmente yo hablo con *[vos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voseo)*, no con *tú*, pero no me hace ninguna diferencia.)

Comment: entendido, gracias. ¿Puedes comprobar, por favor, mi otra pregunta sobre "had been doing" aquí spanish.stackexchange.com/q/35266/23475 ? Aunque ya recibí la respuesta allí y ya la acepté, habrá una respuesta diferente de ti.